# Is mining uneconomic in Belgium?

Tags: altcoin, mining-profitability

[A Belgian website](http://www.vreg.be/nl/hoeveel-kost-1-kwh-elektriciteit-en-aardgas) says the price of electricity in Belgium is between 0.22 and 0.44 Euros/kWh.

[image: graph of prices over three years]

> For electricity [...]
>
> - low consumption (orange curve: Da - 600 kWh single consumption on an annual basis, 1 person),
> - average consumption (blue curve: Dc - 1,600 kWh daily consumption and 1,900 kWh night consumption on an annual basis, 3 people),
> - high consumption (green curve: De - 3,600 kWh daily consumption, 3,900 kWh night consumption and 12,500 kWh annual nightly consumption only, 4 people).

I have an Antminer S9 which uses 1600W.

I have a CPU/11 GPU rig which uses 1200W.

Is it uneconomic to do mining in Belgium? (As in that there won't be any profit because all mining gains will be taken away by electricity costs?)

How to fix it, so that I have at least some profit?

Comment: I think you meant 'unprofitable'

Comment: This is an English-language site.  Could you explain what the graph is supposed to be showing?